# Collaboratively Developing ORDS Webservices for Another Schema with Multiple Oracle Users

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords

I am currently working with a team to develop Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS), and each team member has a standard Oracle user account. We need to create and modify webservices for another schema in the Oracle Database.

I understand that this might require certain permissions or settings to be adjusted for each user, but I'm not entirely sure what these adjustments are. I also know that we need to manage the collaborative development process effectively so that everyone can work on the same RESTful services without conflict.

Could anyone help clarify the following for me:

- What roles or privileges do our Oracle users need to have to develop ORDS webservices for another schema?
- Are there any specific ORDS settings or configurations that need to be adjusted to allow multiple users to work on the same services?
- How can we effectively manage the development process so that all team members can collaborate on the same RESTful services?

Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. What roles or privileges do our Oracle users need to have to develop
   ORDS webservices for another schema?
2. Are there any specific ORDS
   settings or configurations that need to be adjusted to allow
   multiple users to work on the same services?
3. How can we effectively manage the development process so that all team member
   can collaborate on the same RESTful services?

Answer 1 - the ORDS_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE ([Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/23.2/ordig/miscellaneous-configuration-options-of-ORDS.html#GUID-F5B4FA7C-E7D6-4182-9787-22909194B136)). If your user is granted this, they can execute the ORDS_ADMIN PL/SQL API ([Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/23.2/orddg/oracle-rest-data-services-administration-pl-sql-package-reference.html#GUID-7066858A-6CB8-48C8-9557-27CAD67FB3D0)). This allows you to publish REST APIs for ANY ORDS enabled schema/user in the database.

Answer 2 - No, just sort #1

Answer 3 - The same you would do with your PL/SQL programs. Use SOURCE CONTROL to manage the PL/SQL definitions of your APIs, and/or use SQLcl with Liquibase changeLogs for your REST APIs - those would also be put under source control.

Comment: To 1. I Use the SQL Developer. There is a small Window für the Rest Config. I Only can see my rest config there?!

Comment: Sorry @Jensk I don't understand your question. I never said to use SQL Developer and REST Config...for issue one, you only need to grant the database role 'ORDS_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE' to any database user that needs the ability to manage REST APIs, Clients, etc for any schema in the database.